# Using lodash implicit function chaining in order to work on an array of objects

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

I would like to use **lodash** function chaining in order to iterate over an array of objects, and push each of the object values into a new array.

I could use a nested `forEach` for that purpose but I understand there are better ways.

I want to turn this array from:

```
[
 {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'},
 {a: 'baz', b: 'foo2'},
 {a: 'bar2', b: 'baz2'}
]
```

into the following result:

```
[
 'foo','bar','baz', 'foo2', 'bar2', 'baz2'
]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `_.flatMap(Object.values)`?

Comment: It is a builtin JavaScript function. Gets an array of the values in an object. [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks

Comment: [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) should be in the next version of JavaScript so you would just write: `myObjects.flatMap(Object.values)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon Aluan Haddad's comment, I came up with the following solution:

```
   const theArray = [
     {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'},
     {a: 'baz', b: 'foo2'},
     {a: 'bar2', b: 'baz2'}
    ];

    _(theArray)
    .flatMap(Object.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is how to do this without lodash

```
theArray.reduce( (acc,item) => acc.concat(Object.values(item)) , [] )
```

For those into recycling and watching their weight

```
const concatWith = (fn,a,b) => a.concat(fn(b))
theArray.reduce( concatWith.bind(null,Object.values) , [] )
```

Or just use a curry function

```
const curry = (fn, ...args) => 
  fn.length <= args.length ?  fn(...args) : curry.bind(null, fn, ...args)
```

and do it this way

```
const concatWith = curry( (fn,a,b) => a.concat(fn(b)) )
theArray.reduce( concatWith(Object.values) , [] )
```

Enjoy!